# Bash script isn't expanding my $file variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The elif statement prints the string `$file` literally instead of the variable's value. How can I fix this?

```
  while read file
    do
    file_time=$(du -s --time "$directory/$file" | cut -f2)
    if [ -d "$directory/$file" ]; then
      if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
        content+="<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$file/index.html\">$file</a></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
      else
        content+="<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$directory/$file/index.html\">$file</a></td></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right">  - <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
      fi
    elif [ -f "$directory/$file" ]; then
      file_size=$(du -h "$directory/$file" | cut -f1)
      if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
        content+="<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$file/index.html\">$file</a></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
      else
        content+='<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$directory/$file\">$file</a></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'
     fi  
    fi

 done < <(ls -1 --group-directories-first $directory --ignore=index.html --ignore=icons --ignore=pictures --ignore=make_index.sh --ignore=good.sh)
```

Comment: The single quotes did nothing. First the created index.html file has $file  $file_time $file_size instead of the values. Second if I insert and echo $file in the elif statement it is empty.

Comment: But what you mean? What is lost? Please show the output of that `ls` command and the output of the while loop, and point out where something's missing. Note that [parsing `ls` is generally discouraged](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
>   content+="<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$file/index.html\">$file</a></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
> else
>   content+='<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$directory/$file\">$file</a></td><td align="right">$file_time  </td><td align="right"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'
> fi
> ```

Compare the syntax highlighting in the two long lines. In the first there is a mix of red and black text. The second is all red. Why? You're not using the same quotes: one starts with `"` and the other with `'`.

- Variables aren't expanded in single quotes, so I don't recommend `'`. You want `$file` to be expanded and it's not if it's in single quotes.
- The double quote version allows `$file` to be expanded. However, the embedded double quotes are a problem. As the syntax highlighting indicates, you're not actually *embedding* quotes. Rather, you're repeatedly starting and ending double quotes sections.

Switch the single quotes to double quotes, and then escape all the embedded quotes with `\"`. That'll fix the red/black syntax highlighting.

```
if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
  content+="<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/icons/unknown.gif\" alt=\"[   ]\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$file/index.html\">$file</a></td><td align=\"right\">$file_time  </td><td align=\"right\"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
else
  content+="<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/icons/unknown.gif\" alt=\"[   ]\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" /></td><td><a href=\"$root_directory/$directory/$file\">$file</a></td><td align=\"right\">$file_time  </td><td align=\"right\"> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
fi
```

Or use single quotes in the HTML. Then you don't need any ugly backslashes. HTML allows either type of quote to be used.

```
if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
  content+="<tr><td valign='top'><img src='/icons/unknown.gif' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='$root_directory/$file/index.html'>$file</a></td><td align='right'>$file_time  </td><td align='right'> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
else
  content+="<tr><td valign='top'><img src='/icons/unknown.gif' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='$root_directory/$directory/$file'>$file</a></td><td align='right'>$file_time  </td><td align='right'> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
fi
```

---

The whole thing would be easier to read if you unconditionally add the common bits of HTML.

```
content+="<tr><td valign='top'><img src='/icons/unknown.gif' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td>"
if [ "$directory" == "." ]; then
  content+="<a href='$root_directory/$file/index.html'>"
else
  content+="<a href='$root_directory/$directory/$file'>"
fi  
content+="$file</a></td><td align='right'>$file_time  </td><td align='right'> $file_size </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
```

Comment: Another way way would be using printf to a variable, then appending that variable after the if/else blocks, ex: `printf -v newcontents '<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16" /></td><td><a href="%s/%s/index.html">%s</a></td><td align="right"> %s </td><td align="right"> %s </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>' "$root_directory" "$file" "$file" "$file_time" "$file_size"`. Also since only few things change between the 4 contents lines it could be cleaner to set those as variable and have only one HTML line with more variables.